# Error installing RMagick on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, macports, rmagick

I am trying to install **RMagick** to use it in a Rails application, but i'm experiencing some problems.

I'm using **Rails 5** with **Ruby 2.3.1** installed using rvm. The OS it's **OSX 10.6** and i've already installed **ImageMagick** using **macports**.

When Bundler try to install the RMagick gem i can see that the installation fails and looking in the log i can see the following result:

```
find_executable: checking for clang... -------------------- yes
find_executable: checking for Magick-config... -------------------- yes
configure_compile_options: checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.4.9)... no
Detected ImageMagick version: 6.9.5
configure_compile_options: checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no
Detected 6.9+ version, using MagickWand API
assert_minimum_ruby_version!: checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5...  yes
"clang -o conftest -I/Users/jonny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin10.0 
-I/Users/jonny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward 
-I/Users/jonny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  
-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 
-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 
-I/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6  -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 
-DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 
-DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 
-I/opt/local/include/ImageMagick-6 conftest.c  -L. 
-L/Users/jonny/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib -L/opt/local/lib  
-L/opt/local/lib -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16    
-L/opt/local/lib -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16  
-lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc "
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Someone have a solution to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by myself the problem. The problem arise because older version of **clang** doesn't support *openmp* so we have to install a newer version.

Using **macports** i've installed another version of **clang** enabling the *openmp* version.

```
sudo port install clang-3.7 +openmp
```

After the installation i've checked the name of the clang installed using the command

```
sudo port select --list clang
```

The new clang installed name was *mp-clang-3.7* so typing in the console

```
sudo port select --set clang mp-clang-3.7
```

select the correct version.

After doing that i could install correctly **RMagick** using bundle.